# Searching sub string through 3Million Records in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge Data frame which has 3M records which has column called description. Also I have possible sub string set of around 5k.

I want to get the rows in which the description contains any of the sub string.

i used the following looping

```
for i in range(0,len(searchstring)): 
 ss=searchsting[i]
 for k in range(0,len(df)):
    desc=df['description'].iloc[k].lower()
    if (bool(re.search(ss,desc))):
        trans.append(df.iloc[k])
```

The issue is it is taking too much time as the search 5k times 3M looping.

Is there any better way to search substring?

Comment: I would suggest using a HashMap for your larger set of records, this will be expensive in memory. But then can check if a record exists within this set and that would be in 0(1) time for each record.

Comment: You use `re.search` ... are these substrings regular expressions?

Comment: these are substrings only   ss=re.compile(re.escape(searchstring[]i.lower()))

Comment: Assuming that you have a 5k list of search strings (none of this re.compile business), I think you can select them in the dataframe with `df['description'].str.lower().isin(search_strings_list)` and you can use that selection to remove non-conforming rows from the dataframe. So, `df[df['description'].str.lower().isin(search_strings_list)]`. its easy to try... let me know if it works!

Comment: It might even be possible to do `isin(set(search_strings_list))` for a bit of a boost.

Comment: `df[df.isin({'description':sub_string_set}).any(1)]` ... [Indexing with isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin). - `sub_string_set` can be a set or a list.

Comment: @tdelaney didnt work. I got empty string as i dont have any exact match in the description column. I guess isin only returns the if the enter value matches not the substring. I'm not an expert python user.

Comment: @wwii Im not sure about indexing in isin. I tried the code you have given  but got the following error.SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001A7F47CFF30> returned a result with an error set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas).  The accepted answer has an `isin()` solution/example which is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative method. I have created a word dictionary for the description column of 3M data set, by splitting each words. (I have replaced numbers in the description with zeros and used it for dictionary generation)

```
def tokenize(desc):

   desc=re.sub('\d', '0', desc)
   tokens=re.split('\s+',desc)
   return tokens

def make_inv_index(df):
  inv_index={}
  for i,tokens in df['description_removed_numbers'].iteritems():
     for token in tokens:
         try:
              inv_index[token].append(i)
         except KeyError:
              inv_index[token]=[i]

  return inv_index
df['description_removed_numbers']=df['description'].apply(tokenize)
inv_index_df=make_inv_index(df)
```

Now while searching the description, have to apply the same tokenization on the the search string and will take intersection of indexes of that particular words using the dictionary and will search only those fields. This substantially reduced my overall time taken to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Should be faster if you use pandas `isin()` function

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
a ='Hello world'
ss = a.split(" ")

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Hello', 'asd', 'asdasd', 'world']})
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(ss)].index
```

Returns a list of indexes:

```
Int64Index([0, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: I guess is in wont search for substring in a particular column.

Comment: I think it is searching in a particular column if you call isin() on the column. I did some simple checks while giving this answer and if was possible searching on one column

Comment: [Indexing with isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)